# How do we prove or disprove that $\sqrt{x} \lt x$ for all $x \gt 1$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Here is my attempt:
Suppose otherwise and let $\sqrt{x} = x$ then $$\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}\implies 1=\sqrt{x}$$ which means that $$\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}=1.1=1=x $$ but we are assuming $x\gt1$
so this leads to a contradiction.
Now let $\sqrt{x} > x$ then $$\sqrt{x} \gt\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}\implies 1\gt\sqrt{x}$$
I am stuck at this place and will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$x-\sqrt x=\sqrt x(\sqrt x -1)$. This is a product of two positive numbers and  hence it is positive.

[Note that $(\sqrt x -1)(\sqrt x +1)=x-1>0$. Since $\sqrt x +1>0$ it follows that $\sqrt x -1 >0$].

Comment: Yes $\sqrt{x}$ is a positive number. But how to know if $\sqrt{x}-1$ is also a positive number

Comment: Write it as $\frac a b$ where $a=x-1$ and $y=\sqrt x+1$.

Comment: I could not understand your comment in which you mentioned about writing it as a/b. I proceeded as follows. Since $x \gt 1$, we must have $\sqrt{x} \gt 1$. Because $0 \lt \sqrt{x} \lt 1 \implies 0 \lt \sqrt{x}\sqrt{x} \lt 1 \implies 0 \lt x \lt 1$. Then  $$\sqrt{x} \gt 1 \implies \sqrt{x} -1 \gt 1-1 \implies \sqrt{x} -1 \gt 0$$

Comment: The negation of $\sqrt x >1$ is $\sqrt x \leq 1$, not $\sqrt x <1$. I have added some details to my answer. @RajkumarKumawat

Comment: The case $\sqrt{x}=1$ was obvious. Because $x=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}=1.1=1$ which will contradict our assumption that $x \gt 1$. Any way you modified answer explains clearly why $\sqrt{x}-1 \gt 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically done. You've been asked to prove $x\gt1\implies \sqrt x\lt x$, and what you've proved is the *contrapositive*, $\sqrt x\ge x\implies x\le1$.

Answer (score 1):

> $ 1 > \sqrt{x}$ [...] I'm stuck at this place.

Square both sides, i.e.

$$0 <a < b \iff 0 < a^2 < b^2 .$$

PS I think you should make it clearer that you are splitting into two cases $x = \sqrt x$ and $x< \sqrt x$, but you don't need to do this split in the first place because you can just replace all your $>$s with $\ge$s and the proof will work.

Answer (score 1):

Just notice that if $\sqrt x \ge x> 1$ then it follows than

$x =\sqrt x*\sqrt x > 1*\sqrt x= \sqrt x$ which contradicts our assumption.

Answer (score 1):

For $x>1$,

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt x} = \sqrt x > 1$$

Thus,

$$x>\sqrt x$$

Answer (score 0):

$$x>\sqrt x \rightarrow \sqrt x>1$$

$\sqrt x=1$ at $x=1$ and $\sqrt x$ monotonically increases so $\sqrt x>1$ for $x>1$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the function $f(x)=x-\sqrt{x}$ for $x \in \mathbb R^+$. As you already found out the only zero is at $x=1$. Because it is continuous the sign can't chance for $x>1$ (intermediate value theorem). So it's enought to check the sign for one value, for example $x=4$. We have $f(4)=4-2=2>0$. Hence $f(x)>0$ for all $x>1$. So $x>\sqrt {x}$ for all $x>1$.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality $\sqrt x < x$ is equivalent to $x<x^2$ when squaring both sides since $x>1$.
The latter is equivalent to $x^2-x>0$ for $x>1$. Now you could imagine a graphic solution: the parabola $y=x^2$ grows faster than the line $y=x$ for $x>1$.